# How do I Edit a app.xaml file in runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can I Edit a App.xaml in WPF in runtime? 
ps. Trying to add a resource dictionary in a MergedDictionaries, but the file do not edit

Comment: It makes no sense to edit an actual XAML file at runtime because the XAML is compiled into BAML. The actual XAML markup in the source file is not used at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Trying to add a resource dictionary in a `MergedDictionaries`, but the file do not edit

Modifying the actual XAML source file at runtime will have no effect on the running app. That's because XAML files are compiled into BAML resources when you build, and the running app uses these BAML resources rather than the actual XAML source files.

XAML files should be created and modified by developers at design time. They are not used at runtime.

You can of course write to the actual source file in the project folder just like you would write to any other XML or text file, but it won't affect the running app.

Comment: thx, that was very **enlightening**, I will try to modify the xaml doc then

Answer (score 1):

You don't edit the App.xaml file at runtime, but you can add a `ResourceDictionary` into the `MergedDictionaries` via code:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(yourResourceDictionary);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this option, but the app.xaml file didn't edit, the dictionaries that i added, they added only in runtime, so the app.xaml remains the same after it